# How to embed moving ads on the sides of webpage(forums)

Tags: html

I intend to display some ads on the sides of my website which move up and down as the user scrolls the long webpage(forum topics etc)

Firstly i am a novice who does not know what to call such containers which move. so can somebody tell me if they have any technical names ?so that i can update my query

Then the question comes to is it HTML, PHP etc.

I am not a big web programmer, but i am on a learning curve. so any suggestions, help is appreciated

Comment: Do you mean that they move relative to the rest of the page content, but actually stay in the same location on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `CSS`.

Create a div which contain your ads, and add `position:fixed` style to the div.

For example, your html:

```
<div class="ad">
   ...
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.ad{
   position:fixed
}
```

**Edit :** An example here :
http://fiddle.jshell.net/tTdu3/